# Moving form content which is located under the keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikeyboard

I am using `UITableView`, where each cell contains a `UITextField`, and using Apple official example, I wish to perform goal, moving the active field above the keyboard if it's already hidden. However, the form doesn't move although the `UITableView` is scroll eabled. Here is my relevant code, please help me pointing on what seems to be missing/wrong:

```
@interface ViewController (){
    UITextField *activeField;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//....
    objTableView.scrollEnabled=YES;

//....
}

#pragma mark - Keyboard notifications

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications

{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)

                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)

                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;



    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    objTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;

    objTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;



    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible

    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {

        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);

        [objTableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    }

}



// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    objTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;

    objTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate protocol method

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

    activeField = textField;

}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

    activeField = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGRect rc = [activeField bounds];
    rc = [activeField convertRect:rc toView:objTableView];
    [objTableView scrollRectToVisible:rc animated:YES];
}
```